# Are normal light waves more dangerous than WiFi radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, microwaves

I'm getting sort of tired of all the "wireless hysteria", so I thought this might be a nice comment.

To the extent of my knowledge, WiFi uses microwaves, which have a lower frequency and hence carry less energy than light.

Is normal light therefore more dangerous to us than WiFi waves?

Comment: This is basically a human health question, though it should be clear that physics plays a role and that one can reason from fundamental physics to find an envelope in which the answer most lie. Nonetheless I feel that it is not a *physics* question as such. And, indeed, the answer that it has attracted to date is not a physics answer.

Comment: If you would like I can inquire of the Biology mods if they want it.

Comment: I have asked the bio mods, but no answer yet. There are only three of them and I don't know what timezones they may be in or if they even look in on weekends.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of light you are talking about. Sunlight, for example, is known for sure to be dangerous for humans, since there is conclusive experimental evidence. Note that the dangerous part of the frequency spectrum is not in the visible range.

It is also known through lengthy exposure of humans to the visible spectrum from artificial lighting that this radiation is safe, as long as the intensity is low.

Microwaves have been around much less than the above and, even though I don't know the current status of research in that field, the implications of lengthy exposure cannot be assessed as easily as for visible light.

The statement I would make would therefore be: there is no conclusive evidence that exposure to WiFi microwaves is more dangerous than equal exposure to light.